# Android Full Text Search

Tags: android, database, sqlite, full-text-search, android-room

Does Android come with a way to do [Full Text Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search)?

I know [is it not even possible to search contacts by the notes field](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3732), being Google the search company, but I would be disappointed if there is no API for that.

Comment: See [Full text search example in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29815248)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to provide [Full Text Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search) is to use [FTS3](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) in [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 0):

## SQLite Database With Android's Room Library

Android's [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) library provides full-text search using SQLite.

*See: [Support full-text search](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#fts)*

## Firebase Firestore Database

Google's Firebase Firestore outlines a [full-text search solution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) using a 3rd party service, Algolia. Other 3rd party services can be used like [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/).

Answer (score -1):

[Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) is another approach, faster than SQLite FTS

Comment: The Most Popular RDBMS library that is supported in by default is SQLite –